# xcode delete all data from coder archive

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I am using state restoration for my view controllers in Xcode 7.1. But whenever the app initiates on either the simulator or iPhone the old tableview appears. It has rows in it I want to get rid of but my delete code doesn't work.  Is there some way to delete coder archived data from a previous build so I get a completely clean tableview to start? I tried  in the build target but that didn't help. If I could find where the coder archived data lives in the simulator and get rid of it, maybe that might work?

Here is the state restoration code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. I was looking for the DocumentsDirectory in Library/Developer.  Here is a link
to a discussion that answered my question. I was able to go in there and delete the *.archive files that were giving me trouble. To be more specific, I incorrectly added some arrays to sections in a tableView, and used State Restoration to save them when I killed the app in Xcode. Then my delete code got exceptions for iterating outside the arrays so I couldn't get rid of them programmatically. But by deleting the archive files using this procedure, I am back in business.

[link to access documents directory](https://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/11/28/ios8-simulator-documents-directory/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the Derived Data? Xcode allows you to delete the folder, it contains the index, build output and logs. However, I would do a clean then build first, then reset the simulator settings if necessary.

To delete the Derived Data: Window > Projects > select your project and delete